# Is it grammatically correct to repeat object in a relative clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Suppose we have the following relative clause:

> Have you seen those people whom we met on holiday?

Is it correct to add a pronoun and change it in the following way?

> Have you seen those people whom we met **them** on holiday?

Comment: I don't particularly see this as grammatically correct; it also reads awkwardly.

Comment: I think such usages *might* have been idiomatic a couple of centuries ago. I also think including the referent ***them*** as per the example is something that typically happens in Romance languages (Spanish, French,...). But I ***know*** it's ***not*** valid in current English.

Comment: No: the relative clause already has "whom" as object of "met", so we can't add another one!

Comment: Thanks I got it. Please write this as an answer so I can mark this question answered. 

Answer (score 1):

[***Who/whom*** is a pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_(pronoun)). It does not make sense to add another pronoun.

Comment: additionally, it sounds quite "repelling"